# How to automatically create wordpress posts for each mp3 uploaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, id3v2

I have a wordpress site, and its about media sharing. I have uploaded mp3 files as albums and created a post for each album. But I want to create individual post for each mp3 files uploaded automatically.

I have already tried mp3-to-post plugin, but that's not supported for the latest version of wordpress and I have tried uploading the plugin, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `do_action( 'add_attachment', $post_ID )` hook you can create respective post. For ref - see [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function

To do the above, add follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function action_add_attachment( $post_ID ) { 
    if( !$post_ID ) return;
    $attachment = get_post( $post_ID );
    // Create album post object for attachment post ID
    $attachment_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'Album - ' . $attachment->post_title,
      'post_content'  => 'Your post content goes here',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => $attachment->post_author
    );

    // Insert the post 
    wp_insert_post( $attachment_post );
}

add_action( 'add_attachment', 'action_add_attachment', 99 );
```

Comment: where do I type this command?. and btw, I didn't upload any mp3 files as attachments. I uploaded using ftp.

Comment: hi, itzmekhokan. how do I implement this, are there any tutorials about it?

Comment: @brvnbld, I just updated above answer with a code snippet. Please check the above.

Comment: So, I just input these in the theme's functions.php, and each attachment page is populated by the mp3's metadata. Am I correct?. Do I also need that plugin for this to be done?. Will this convert all attachment pages to be populated with the data(even existing)?